# how to extract the first and last filled block of columns from a data.frame?

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe, data-cleaning

We have a log data for file download time.

For every individual transaction there will be a start and end timestamp.

**Raw Data in excel**

[image]

Each individual row is one transaction with several downloads. Every download has a block of 3 columns with the start date, start time (hh:mm.ss) and start milliseconds. The first 3 columns of each row are the start time, the last 3 cell values in a row are end time.

I want to prepare the data in such a way that there should be only the three columns of the first and the last download of each transaction (= row) in one row as below.

[image]

I am using INDIRECT and ADDRESS function in excel to get the work done.

Can this be done in R?

I have loaded data to R and it looks as below. Empty cell values are stored as NA.

`nov <-read.csv(file = '././data/NovemberResults-uniq.csv',header = T,na.strings = FALSE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

**Data in R**

[image]

dput result:

```
> dput(x = nov[1,])
structure(list(SD1 = structure(1L, .Label = "01-11-2015", class = "factor"), 
    ST1 = structure(1L, .Label = c(" 00:00:01", " 00:00:02", 
    " 00:00:11", " 00:00:13", " 00:00:27", " 00:00:28", " 01:13:16"
    ), class = "factor"), SMS1 = 323L, SD2 = structure(1L, .Label = " 2015-11-01 ", class = "factor"), 
    ST2 = structure(1L, .Label = c(" 00:00:01", " 00:00:02", 
    " 00:00:12", " 00:00:14", " 00:00:27", " 00:00:29", " 01:13:25"
    ), class = "factor"), SMS2 = 551L, SD3 = structure(1L, .Label = c("", 
    " 2015-11-01 "), class = "factor"), ST3 = structure(1L, .Label = c("", 
    " 00:00:27", " 01:13:33"), class = "factor"), SMS3 = NA_integer_, 
    SD4 = structure(1L, .Label = c("", " 2015-11-01 "), class = "factor"), 
    ST4 = structure(1L, .Label = c("", " 01:13:44"), class = "factor"), 
    SMS4 = NA_integer_), .Names = c("SD1", "ST1", "SMS1", "SD2", 
"ST2", "SMS2", "SD3", "ST3", "SMS3", "SD4", "ST4", "SMS4"), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")


SD1 ST1 SMS1    SD2 ST2 SMS2    SD3 ST3 SMS3    SD4 ST4 SMS4
01-11-2015   00:00:01   323  2015-11-01      00:00:01   551                     
01-11-2015   00:00:02   289  2015-11-01      00:00:02   618                     
01-11-2015   01:13:16   253  2015-11-01      01:13:25   511  2015-11-01      01:13:33   489  2015-11-01      01:13:44   870
01-11-2015   00:00:11   986  2015-11-01      00:00:12   602                     
01-11-2015   00:00:27   48   2015-11-01      00:00:27   391  2015-11-01      00:00:27   429         
01-11-2015   00:00:13   750  2015-11-01      00:00:14   255                     
01-11-2015   00:00:28   773  2015-11-01      00:00:29   114
```

Comment: Did you try something? Please, show your effort.

Comment: I was referring to `R`. Did you import the data? Did you see how they look in R? Can you subset an object?

Comment: Yes I have imported data into R. the blanks cells are seen as NA.
`nov <-read.csv(file = '././data/NovemberResults-uniq.csv',header = T,na.strings = FALSE,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: Since you are asking a `R` question, you should post the data you have in `R`. What you got in Excel is pretty irrelevant. Post the output of `dput(df)` (change `df` with the actual name of the object). Do you know how to find the first `NA` of a row and how to subset an object?

Comment: ` dput(nov[2,])
structure(list(Start_Date1 = "01-11-2015", Start_Time1 = " 00:00:02", 
    Start_Millisecond1 = 289L, Start_Date2 = " 2015-11-01 ", 
    Start_Time2 = " 00:00:02", Start_Millisecond2 = 618L, Start_Date3 = "", 
    Start_Time3 = "", Start_Millisecond3 = NA_integer_, Start_Date4 = "", 
    Start_Time4 = "", Start_Millisecond4 = NA_integer_), .Names = c("Start_Date1", 
"Start_Time1", "Start_Millisecond1", "Start_Date2", "Start_Time2", 
"Start_Millisecond2", "Start_Date3", "Start_Time3", "Start_Millisecond3", 
"Start_Date4", "Start_Time4", "Start_Millisecond4")`

dput output

Comment: Sorry, it would be easier for us if you could add more than one example row from your data **into the question** using `dput`. The examples should contain all possible variations of your problem (e. g. different number of recorded transaction events per row) so that we can test our answer easily. Thanks :-)

Comment: So find out the last block columns containing data I propose the `rle` or `rowSums(is.na(nov))` functions, then extract the first block of columns (first three) as start event and the last available (end event) by using the last three columns of each row (we do know now by performing a little calculation)

Comment: ` rowSums(is.na(nov))

[1] 2 2 0 2 1 2 2`

In data the columns date and time are factors and the millisecond is Int.

Comment: Please add more than one row to your question (e. g. `nov[1:20,]`), one or two rows are not enough. Your example does also not contain `NA`s in all empty "cells" but strings of length zero which makes is more difficult to process. Is this really the result of `read.csv` or did you manually edit the data in Excel?

Comment: I have added more rows of data and the pic of the data looks in R.
There are no NA's Exist in excel csv.  
To add one more thing from column 3 there is a space in every cell value in first position.

Comment: @sandeep Do you allow me to edit (rephrase) your question so that others could find the question better (e. g. using a headline like "how to extract the first and last filled block of columns from a data.frame"? Or do it yourself of course :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fast solution for an **arbitrary number of transaction event columns** could be achieved using a `data.table`:

```
# Preconditions for this solution:
# 1. Three columns per transaction event (download): Date, time, milliseconds
# 2. The download columns are at the beginning of the data.frame
# 3. There are no gaps within the downloads of row (in other words: NAs are always at the end)
# 4. Sufficient performance is only guaranteed if the number of columns is not to high (guess: several thousands)

# For efficiency I use a data.table instead of a data.frame
library(data.table)

# Read the data into a data.table using "white spaces" as separator.
# Important: Disable factors + interpret emtpy strings as "NA"
data <- read.table(header=TRUE, fill=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, na.strings="", text=
                     "SD1    ST1 SMS1    SD2 ST2 SMS2    SD3 ST3 SMS3    SD4 ST4 SMS4
01-11-2015   00:00:01   323  2015-11-01      00:00:01   551
01-11-2015   00:00:02   289  2015-11-01      00:00:02   618
01-11-2015   01:13:16   253  2015-11-01      01:13:25   511  2015-11-01      01:13:33   489  2015-11-01      01:13:44   870
01-11-2015   00:00:11   986  2015-11-01      00:00:12   602
01-11-2015   00:00:27   48   2015-11-01      00:00:27   391  2015-11-01      00:00:27   429
01-11-2015   00:00:13   750  2015-11-01      00:00:14   255
01-11-2015   00:00:28   773  2015-11-01      00:00:29   114"
)

# Convert the data.frame into a data.table for efficient performance (and better processing syntax)
setDT(data)

# Specify the max. number of downloads per transaction in the data.frame.
# Since each download has three columns (data + time + milliseconds) derive this value from "ncol".
# If you have additional data columns you must set this value manually
max.num.of.downloads = ncol(data) / 3

# Calculate the number of empty cells ("columns") per row and add this value as new columns
data[, num.NA.cells := rowSums(is.na(data[, 1:(max.num.of.downloads*3), with=FALSE]))]

# Rough validation that NAs are consistent (three NAs per missing download)
stopifnot( nrow(data[(num.NA.cells %% 3) != 0,]) == 0 )

# Add a column containing the number of downloads
data[, downloads.count := max.num.of.downloads - (num.NA.cells / 3)]

# Now the big magic: For each group of data with the same transaction count: Add the "transaction end" columns.
# Note:
# a) .SD is a data table containing only the sub data (SD!) of the current group
# b) "with=FALSE" allows column indexes instead of names
# c) := is assignment by reference (creates new columns if they do not exist)
# d) The outer parens around the column names to be created ("SD.End") are required if you create or update more than one column at once with ":="
data[, (c("SD.End", "ST.End", "SMS.End")) := .SD[, seq((downloads.count - 1) * 3 + 1 , (downloads.count - 1) * 3 + 3), with=FALSE],
     by=downloads.count]

# data[, .N, by=downloads.count]  # just for debugging: Count the number of rows per downloads.count group

# "data" was now enriched with everything you need. Now you can just "cut out" what you need:
data[, .(SD1, ST1, SMS1, SD.End, ST.End, SMS.End)]
```

The result is the same:

```
> data[, .(SD1, ST1, SMS1, SD.End, ST.End, SMS.End)]
          SD1      ST1 SMS1     SD.End   ST.End SMS.End
1: 01-11-2015 00:00:01  323 2015-11-01 00:00:01     551
2: 01-11-2015 00:00:02  289 2015-11-01 00:00:02     618
3: 01-11-2015 01:13:16  253 2015-11-01 01:13:44     870
4: 01-11-2015 00:00:11  986 2015-11-01 00:00:12     602
5: 01-11-2015 00:00:27   48 2015-11-01 00:00:27     429
6: 01-11-2015 00:00:13  750 2015-11-01 00:00:14     255
7: 01-11-2015 00:00:28  773 2015-11-01 00:00:29     114
```

Comment: I could just say Wow!!!... R Yoda i was trying in the same context... your solution is just mind blowing... I don't know why am not able to solve these... but still i will try to solve it on own... thanks

Comment: Forgot to add one point.. R yoda, In the above code if i use the data.table  to load the data i get a error message as below. I am not using Text = as the data is almost 700000+ so am using file path.

`data <- read.table(file = "./data/NovemberResults-uniq.csv",header = TRUE,strip.white = TRUE,na.strings = "",stringsAsFactors = F)
Error in read.table(file = "./data/NovemberResults-uniq.csv", header = TRUE,  : 
  more columns than column names`

Comment: @sandeep Looks like your data has some rows with more columns than others (or the first column with the header names has less columns). This is a data error problem. Please try to locate the offending line of data. Perhaps the `fread` function of the `data.table` package is more helpful to find the row than `read.table` (and much faster!).

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring type conversions (e. g. date + time character columns into one "datetime" POSIXct colum) a possible solution could be:

```
# Read the data into a data.table using "white spaces" as separator.
# Important: Disable factors + interpret emtpy strings as "NA"
data <- read.table(header=TRUE, fill=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, na.strings="", text=
"SD1    ST1 SMS1    SD2 ST2 SMS2    SD3 ST3 SMS3    SD4 ST4 SMS4
01-11-2015   00:00:01   323  2015-11-01      00:00:01   551
01-11-2015   00:00:02   289  2015-11-01      00:00:02   618
01-11-2015   01:13:16   253  2015-11-01      01:13:25   511  2015-11-01      01:13:33   489  2015-11-01      01:13:44   870
01-11-2015   00:00:11   986  2015-11-01      00:00:12   602
01-11-2015   00:00:27   48   2015-11-01      00:00:27   391  2015-11-01      00:00:27   429
01-11-2015   00:00:13   750  2015-11-01      00:00:14   255
01-11-2015   00:00:28   773  2015-11-01      00:00:29   114"
)

# Just for debugging purposes...
data
str(str)

# Append last available block of transaction event columns to the end
# ("ifelse" since the decision in which column to find the "last value" must be taken on a row-by-row base)
data$SD.End <- ifelse(!is.na(data$SD4),data$SD4,
                     ifelse(!is.na(data$SD3),data$SD3,
                            ifelse(!is.na(data$SD2),data$SD2, NA)))
data$ST.End <- ifelse(!is.na(data$ST4),data$ST4,
                     ifelse(!is.na(data$ST3),data$ST3,
                            ifelse(!is.na(data$ST2),data$ST2, NA)))
data$SMS.End <- ifelse(!is.na(data$SMS4),data$SMS4,
                   ifelse(!is.na(data$SMS3),data$SMS3,
                          ifelse(!is.na(data$SMS2),data$SMS2, NA)))

data

# Now prepare the output by "cutting" the wanted result into a new data.frame
result <- data.frame(c( data[,1:3], data[, 13:15]))

# show result
result
```

The result is:

```
> result
         SD1      ST1 SMS1     SD.End   ST.End SMS.End
1 01-11-2015 00:00:01  323 2015-11-01 00:00:01     551
2 01-11-2015 00:00:02  289 2015-11-01 00:00:02     618
3 01-11-2015 01:13:16  253 2015-11-01 01:13:44     870
4 01-11-2015 00:00:11  986 2015-11-01 00:00:12     602
5 01-11-2015 00:00:27   48 2015-11-01 00:00:27     429
6 01-11-2015 00:00:13  750 2015-11-01 00:00:14     255
7 01-11-2015 00:00:28  773 2015-11-01 00:00:29     114
```

The core problem is to avoid loops but still to work on a row-by-row base to decide from which column the available data shall be copied. This must be done "vectorized" to avoid slow performance so I used `ifelse`.

Comment: R Yoda thanks for your support... it works like a genie... If you can guide me to do this dynamic what i mean is here there are 9 columns only but in actual data there are 26+ columns so the Ifelse need to be wrriten 8 times as above... I will try to do it if you give a hint...

Comment: @sandeep OK, this was unclear to me (please mention this requirement in your question). A dynamic solution is more complicated (and in fact my first approach was to find a generic solution but took to much time to investigate). Please give me a few days time since I am "under pressure" currently.

Comment: Okay R yoda i really want to bow to you for your time and effort thanks.

Comment: @sandeep Can I rely on the fact that your data.frame contains three colums per "download" transaction or do you have additional columns "carrying" other data? I a asking this because I want to find out the last column of the last transaction by using the `ncol` function which returns a "wrong" result if other columns exist.

Comment: @sandeep Please see my second answer for a generic solution with an arbitrary number of columns. HIH

Comment: R yoda. For first question as you said  data.frame contains three colums per "download" transaction.